# MS Graph API use of LookupId from a list to another l

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

projectNameLookupId: "1"

projectName_x003a_projectCodeLookupId: "1"

responsibleLookupId: "14"

here are the fields in my 1st sharepoint list and I would like to fetch data from my 2nd sharepoint list using MS Graph with the help of this lookup id, so far here's the request url I've made

```
/sites/${SITE_ID}/lists/${LIST_ID}/items?$expand=fields&$select=id,fields&$filter=startswith(fields/projectName,1)
```

after that I'm receiving an error of invalid filter clause

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track. Please share your actual REST URL. The one in your example seems like a generalization.

Comment: You're likely misrepresenting the field that you were trying to filter on

Answer (score 2):

As [OData Version 4.0](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356) specification states, `startswith` function has the following signature:

```
Edm.Boolean startswith(Edm.String,Edm.String)
```

meaning the expression:

```
$filter=startswith(fields/projectName,1)
                                     ^^^^
                                     expects a string value
```

is *invalid* (and that's the reason why MS Graph complains with `invalid filter clause` error).

Here is a *valid* query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}$expand=fields&$filter=startswith(fields/ProjectNameLookupId,'1')
```